# Adding columns to a binary matroid to make it graphic

Tags: matroid-theory

It is well-known that graphic matroids are binary. Now suppose we have a binary non-graphic matroid $M$ with representing matrix $A$ over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Is there a known way to add a small number of columns to $A$ to obtain a larger matrix $A'$ whose matroid $M'$ would be graphic?

Comment: Hmmm, how can extra cilumns help? Is not a submatroid of a graphic matroid always graphic itself?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, I see now. Thanks for clearing this up for me. Maybe you can suggest something for the underlying question - what I really want to do is get the "closest" graphic matroid for the given binary one.